# How to show only list view items which value is equal to a value in the Json

Tags: android, listview, filtering

iam creating an App which should show the Sights  in a Listview.
The datas are parsed from a json.
At this json there is a column which declares in which City the sight is.
Now i would like to create a kind of a filter which should check the current Cityname with the City values in my Json.
For example there is a Sight in Berlin and my current city is Berlin, the Listview should show it. If the user is in Munich and the sight is in Berlin, the listview shouldnt show this item.
I get the current cityname value from a different Activity in a TextView.
Here is my Listview Activity:

```
public class Locations extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
ArrayList<productforloc> arrayList;
ListView lv;
private String TAG = Locations.class.getSimpleName();
private TextView addressField; //Add a new TextView to your activity_main to display the address
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;
int i = 1;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
String name;



// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://partypeople.bplaced.net/maptest.json";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String cityname = i.getExtras().getString("cityname");
    TextView city = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ort);
    city.setText(cityname);
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Locations.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) this);





runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new ReadJSON().execute(url);
        }
    });

final ImageButton filteropen = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.aufklaupen);
    filteropen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RelativeLayout filter = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.filterloc);
            filter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ImageButton filterclose = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.zuklappen);
            filterclose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            filteropen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
    });
final ImageButton filterclose = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.zuklappen);
    filterclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RelativeLayout filter = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.filterloc);
            filter.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ImageButton filteropen = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.aufklaupen);
            filteropen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            filterclose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}



class ReadJSON extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {






    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return readURL(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String content) {

        try{
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(content);
            JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray("contacts");

            for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++){
                JSONObject po = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                arrayList.add(new productforloc(
                        po.getString("imageurl"),
                        po.getString("name"),
                        po.getString("street"),
                        po.getString("postalcode"),
                        po.getString("musicstyle"),
                        po.getString("musicsecond"),
                        po.getString("entry"),
                        po.getString("opening"),
                        po.getString("agegroup"),
                        po.getString("urlbtn"),
                        po.getString("Fsk"),
                        po.getString("city"),
                        po.getString("bg")

                ));

            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final CustomListAdapterforloc adapter = new CustomListAdapterforloc(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.model,arrayList);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        if(pDialog.isShowing()){
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        }

    }




private String readURL(String url){
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();


   try{
        URL uri = new URL(url);
        URLConnection urlConnection = uri.openConnection();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) !=null){
            content.append(line+"\n");


        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return content.toString();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    productforloc pForloc = arrayList.get(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this,DetailActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra("name",pForloc.getName());
    intent.putExtra("imageurl",pForloc.getImage());
    intent.putExtra("street",pForloc.getStreet());
    intent.putExtra("postalcode",pForloc.getPostalcode());
    intent.putExtra("entry",pForloc.getEntry());
    intent.putExtra("agegroup",pForloc.getAgegroup());
    intent.putExtra("opening",pForloc.getOpening());
    intent.putExtra("urlbtn",pForloc.getUrlbtn());
    intent.putExtra("Fsk",pForloc.getFsk());
    intent.putExtra("city",pForloc.getCity());
    intent.putExtra("musicstyle",pForloc.getMusicstyle());
    intent.putExtra("musicsecond",pForloc.getMusicsecond());
    intent.putExtra("bg",pForloc.getBg());
    startActivity(intent);


}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call

 }



 */
```

}

and here is my Customlistadapter Activity;

```
public class CustomListAdapterforloc extends ArrayAdapter<productforloc>{

ArrayList<productforloc> products;
Context context;
int resource;
public CustomListAdapterforloc(Context context, int resource, List<productforloc> products) {

    super(context, resource, products);
    this.products = (ArrayList<productforloc>) products;
    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView== null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.model,null,true);
    }
    productforloc product = getItem(position);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagelist);
    Picasso.with(context).load(product.getImage()).into(imageView);
    TextView txtName= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.namelist);
    txtName.setText(product.getName());



    return convertView;

}
```

}

Comment: why don't you just keep items you want in your products arraylist? isn't that your solution?

You can also do it before this line,
        final CustomListAdapterforloc adapter = new CustomListAdapterforloc(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.model,arrayList);

Comment: Yes of course, this is what i wanna do but how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

Get current city name from `intent`.

```
String currentCityName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    currentCityName = i.getExtras().getString("cityname");

    ...........
    .................
}
```

Add `condition` to match `cityName` with `currentCityName` before adding `productforloc` object to `ArrayList`:

```
    try {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(content);
        JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray("contacts");

        for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++){
            JSONObject po = ja.getJSONObject(i);

            String cityName = po.getString("city");

            if(!cityName.equals(currentCityName)) {
                arrayList.add(new productforloc(
                    po.getString("imageurl"),
                    po.getString("name"),
                    po.getString("street"),
                    po.getString("postalcode"),
                    po.getString("musicstyle"),
                    po.getString("musicsecond"),
                    po.getString("entry"),
                    po.getString("opening"),
                    po.getString("agegroup"),
                    po.getString("urlbtn"),
                    po.getString("Fsk"),
                    po.getString("city"),
                    po.getString("bg")));
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```